# how to set auto complete option to on

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have many websites like Facebook where we write a email address and we just click a button, from this a list of email address's rolls down.

Can anyone tell me how this is achieved? Can it be done with just HTML or do i need to learn any other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i go on and search a lot and then i found this is very simple!!

you just need is to type autocomplete = "on" and give it a name and then make a submit button

the code goes here:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" autocomplete="on" />
<input type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is accomplished using Javascript or AJAX requests to query the databases "live" and the return a data set. If I understand you correctly like on Facebook where you type in a Friends name and it will pull back a full list of names which may be your friends.

Jquery, Ajax, Javascript, PHP and Mysql would be some good researching points.

It would be worth searching for "How to create a PHP Ajax request to auto populate HTML fields"

If you are referring to Auto Complete within a browser this is a local setting which is controlled by the end user or their administrator and from what I am aware from HTML alone you can not manipulate this.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with Steve's answer. In addition you might want to check out the following:

http://ajaxdump.com/2010/08/11/10-cool-auto-complete-scripts-using-ajaxjquerymootoolsprototype/

http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-plugins.html

Hope it will help you

Comment: Some great starters there David! - Sanmevg If you do not have a basic understanding of PHP, MYSQL and Jquery/Ajax I would not recommend jumping in the deep end.